# $F:\bf C\to\bf D$ a functor with a right adjoint $G$ and $\bf S$ a full subcat of $\bf C$: When does the inclusion have a right adjoint?

Tags: reference-request, category-theory

Suppose a functor $F:\bf C\to\bf D$ has a right adjoint $G$, let $\bf S$ be a full subcategory of $\bf C$, and denote by $I$ the inclusion of $\bf S$ into $\bf C$. What are non-trivial assumptions under which $I$ has itself a right adjoint? Do you know of any reference for the question?

Comment: What does $F$ have to do with $I$? They appear to be totally unrelated. Anyway, you can always apply the general adjoint functor theorem. I don't think there are many major simplifications arising from $I$ being fully faithful.

Comment: It is my impression too, but I am just looking for some results, if any, relating $I$ to $F$ and $G$, possibly under slightly stronger assumptions than the basic ones in the OP.

Comment: The question doesn't make sense, since $F,G$ do not have anything to do with $S,I$. Of course you cannot expect any connection in an answer! When you drop the adjunction $F,G$ from your question, you ask when full subcategories have right adjoints. Well, they are called coreflective subcategories (see Berci's answer) and there is a big theory behind them, which you can find in many books etc. (start googling and math-sci-netting).

Comment: OK, thank you for the hints!

Answer (score 2):

$\bf S$ is then called a [*coreflective* subcategory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflective_subcategory).

Comment: It is useful to know, but how should this answer my question?

Comment: It is still not clear what is the question then. It seems that $F,G$ and $I$ are much independent data.. The assumption you might be looking for is that every object of $\bf C$ has a coreflection in $\bf S$.